# regular expression for hyphen seperated strings

Tags: regex

I created a regular expression for the format XX-XX-XX-XX-XX, where XX is a alphanumeric.

Regular expression is `^[a-z0-9A-Z]{2}-[a-z0-9A-Z]{2}-[a-z0-9A-Z]{2}-[a-z0-9A-Z]{2}$`.
But what I really want to do is to match the below patterns. My string should have one hyphen (-) for each 2 characters.

```
exapmle 1 : XX-            OK
exapmle 2 : XX-X           OK 
exapmle 3 : XX-XX-         OK 
exapmle 4 : XX-XX-XX       OK
exapmle 5 : XX-XX-XX-X     OK
exapmle 6 : XX-XX-X        OK
exapmle 7 : XX-XX--        NOT OK
exapmle 8 : XX-XX-X-       NOT OK
```

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick. You basically want any number (zero or more) of `XX-` followed by zero, one or two `X`:

```
^([0-9A-Za-z]{2}-)*[0-9A-Za-z]{0,2}$
```

Answer (score 2):

The match needs to start with a match of any number of `XX-` strings:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*
```

Depending on the regexp engine you're using, you may be able to use the somewhat more concise `[[:alnum:]]` here.  Note that `[\w\d]` as originally posted is inappropriate for a couple of reasons; see Alan Moore's comment for details.

Getting the last bit is surprisingly difficult, because you have to nest conditional elements.  I.E. the final hyphen only matches if the preceding `X` matches, and that `X` only matches if the first one does.

Note that this approach assumes that you're not limiting the number of `XX-` segments.  In particular, note that it **will match** `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-`.  You can limit the number of `XX-` segments pretty easily, but getting it to not match a hyphen after the fifth `XX` is a little more complicated.

Anyway, back to the explanation.  A following `X` is okay:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*([A-Za-z0-9])?
```

It's also okay if it is followed by another `X`:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])?)?
```

And a final `-` is also okay (assuming that it's preceded by `XX`):

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9]-?)?)?
```

Finally, append `$` to specify that it should take up the whole line:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9]-?)?)?$
```

I've [forked](http://jsfiddle.net/intuited/TUkT6/) SeanA's jsfiddle.  Thanks, Sean!

### update

Thanks to Alan Moore's great job "watching the watchmen" (see the comments), I realized that you can do this quite a bit more simply with

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-)*[A-Za-z0-9]{0,2}$/
```

[An updated fiddle for that RE](http://jsfiddle.net/intuited/TUkT6/3/).

Here you are saying that there can be up to two `X`s at the end of a series of `XX-` segments.  This works because if there is a hyphen at the end, it will just become part of an additional `XX-` segment.

I've left the above info in because it solves a more general problem.  For example, if each of the segments consisted of a letter and a number, you would have to take such an approach.

If you want it to match `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX` but not `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-`, you can use

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}-){0,4}[A-Za-z0-9]{0,2}$/
```

[A forked fiddle for that use case](http://jsfiddle.net/intuited/U4NZk/2/).

Comment: I just scrolled down and saw that you just did about exactly what I did after fixing mine :)  +1

Comment: I'm not _totally_ convinced of the necessity of that second last step. An `XX-` at the end would be matched just by bumping up the count of the `(XX-)*` bit at the start. In other words, I think you could probably get away with `([\w\d]([\w\d])?)?` (or `[\w\d]{0,2}`) as the last term (without a trailing `-?`).

Comment: @paxdiablo: Good point.  Actually, this means that it's pretty easy to to match `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX` without matching `XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-` just by limiting the number of occurrences of the initial `XX-` segment.

Comment: FYI, the meaning of `\w` varies from one regex flavor to the next, but at the minimum it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (so the `\d` is redundant, and it incorrectly matches `_` as well).  `[[:alnum:]]` is probably a better fit, but not all flavors support that syntax.  Since no flavor was specified in the question, it's probably best to use `[a-z0-9A-Z]` like the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this does the trick:

```
/^([\w\d]{2}-)*([\w\d]|([\w\d]{2}-?)?)$/
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/sadkinson/FaQe6/6/

Explanation:

```
/^([\w\d]{2}-)*  -- any number of XX-
([\w\d]          -- either a single X
|([\w\d]{2}-?)?  -- or two Xs and maybe a dash to end
```

UPDATE: I fixed the above based on a very astute observation (+1) by a commenter :)

Comment: This will also match `sadfjhlkj324242`.

Comment: It matches the test data properly didn't it :)... jk, that was dumb by me, its getting late.  I'll work on it and repost